# CriteriaBuilder join two tables with a custom condition

Tags: java, jpa, criteria-api

I want to write this SQL query

```
SELECT *  
FROM A
LEFT OUTER JOIN B
ON A.IDRESOURCE=B.IDRESOURCE AND B.IDLANGUAGE=22;
```

with the JPA Criteria Builder.
I wrote the first part of the join simply with:

```
CriteriaQuery<A> searchQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(A.class);
Root<A> aRoot = searchQuery.from(A.class);
Join<A, B> bJoin= aRoot.join("mappedB", JoinType.LEFT);
```

but I don't know how to implement the condition B.IDLANGUAGE=22.

Is there any way to accomplish this in Criteria Builder?

Comment: what is mappedB

Comment: Hi @charu joshi. It's the attribute name. See the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/From.html#join(java.lang.String,%20javax.persistence.criteria.JoinType))

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use JPA 2.1 `ON` to specify it in the `JOIN` part, which is **not** the same as in the `WHERE`

```
CriteriaQuery<A> searchQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(A.class);
Root<A> aRoot = searchQuery.from(A.class);
Join<A, B> bJoin= aRoot.join("mappedB", JoinType.LEFT);
bJoin.on(criteriaBuilder.equal(bJoin.get("idLanguage"), 22));
```

Comment: what if I wan to add one more condition for a field of table A in same SQL?

Comment: ```... bJoin.on(criteriaBuilder.equal(bJoin.get("idResource"), aRoot.get("idResource")), criteriaBuilder.equal(bJoin.get("idLanguage"), 22));```

Comment: what is the meaning that "mappedB"

Comment: I think it's the shared column between both entities

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, after spending few days with this problem, we have decided to solve it via database views.
So there is a little alternative solution:

1. Create view that joins needed tables together according wanted conditions
2. Create new entity, representing data from this view and annotate it @Immutable, to make it read only
3. Create criteria builder only above this one entity

Also be aware that you entity needs to have UNIQUE Id, so if you use i.e. LEFT JOINs in you view, it might happen that there will be not unique id, and hibernate will have problems with that. So create new Id in you view as compound key, or random generated value.

It is a little workaround solutions, but it worked well for us.

Answer (score -2):

Use `where` and `CriteriaBuilder.equal`.

```
em.select(aRoot).where( criteriaBuilder.equal(bJoin.get("IdLanguage"), 22));
```

Comment: Hello @Nicholas. Does the EM's Where work after the Join? My problem is that the condition must be run as a Join condition, not as a where contition

Comment: Should do, I've used this plenty. It knows the join because you are using `bJoin` in the where clause.

Comment: This is semantically different to specifying the predicates in the join condition.